# Installing XP from the same partition

Tags: windows-xp, boot, installation

I have a rather unusual question.

I have a computer with one disk with valuable data and no removable media. It is not possible to create a new partition on said disk.

Basically what needs to be achieved then is to install the Windows XP operating system from `disk0part0\INSTALL` (which is an install CD copied to that subdir) to `disk0part0\WINDOWS` **without formatting the disk itself**.

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried it in a virtual machine and it seems to be possible.

> **This procedure isn't recommended and may result in data loss. You're performing in on your own risk. Make complete backup first.**
>
> Obviously visible side effects include:
>
> - Non-standard name of Windows directory (eg. `C:\WINDOWS2` instead of `C:\WINDOWS`)
> - Non-standard names of user directories (eg. `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users.WINDOWS2`, `C:\Documents and Settings\gronostaj.COMPUTERNAME-RANDOMSTRING`
>
> Some serious issues may appear later when using system installed in such way.

I'm assuming entire Windows XP installation disk is copied to `C:\INSTALL` and it's the only available partition (thus also the partition that you're reinstalling to).

## The official method

This is the method based on installer provided by Microsoft.

1. Run `C:\INSTALL\Setup.exe`, the official Windows-based installer for XP. Choose to perform clean install. Accept the license, enter serial key (the same one that is currently used is allowed), check settings and correct anything you don't like. Reboot.
2. You will be asked which environment you'd like to boot: your old XP instance or Windows Installer. Choose Installer.
3. Wait until the installer loads. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, accept license. Choose your only partition. Installer will warn you that Windows is already installed there. Agree to install anyway. You will be asked for new Windows folder name. You *have* to choose something different than `\WINDOWS` or things will break. I tried with `\WINDOWS2`. The rest of the installation process is identical as when installing Windows from a disk to a clean drive.
4. When the installation completes, you'll have two Windows XP entries in the boot menu. The first one is the new instance. Boot it and delete any leftovers from the old instance. (described below).

## The unofficial method

If you don't like the official way for whatever reason, here's alternative one. It's relying on some potentially unsafe hacks, so be careful.

1. Open *Disk Management* console (right-click *My Computer*, choose *Manage computer* and *Disk management* in the left panel). Right-click `C:\` drive and choose to change drive letters.
2. In the new window choose to mount the drive in a directory. Create an empty directory on `C:\` drive, call it `mount` and choose it. Now you should have two paths visible for that drive: `C:\` and `C:\mount`.
3. Open the command prompt. Issue the following command:

   ```
    subst W: C:\mount
   ```

   It will mount `C:\mount` directory as a `W:` drive. Remember that `C:\mount` is already a mount point for `C:\`, so we will effectively create an alias for `C:\`. This way we will circumvent two limitations: WinNTSetup (which we will use later) won't let you install to `C:\` while running Windows from `C:\` and Windows won't let you create a drive letter alias for the system drive.
4. Run [WinNTSetup](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/149612-winntsetup-v33/). Configure following options:

   - Installation files directory: `C:\INSTALL`
   - Boot drive: `C:\`
   - Installation drive: `W:\`
   - Windows directory name: enabled, `C:\WINDOWS2` **← this one is important!**

   Click *Setup*, wait until WinNTSetup completes. Reboot.
5. Reboot to Windows installer. The first installation phase will run in unattended mode. It will copy required files and reboot to second phase which goes just like in the official method. Final effect *should* be identical. Remove any leftovers.

## Removing leftovers

*Before removing any leftovers you should copy your files from the old profile to the new one. This includes My Documents and other similar folders.*

Open `C:\` in Windows Explorer, accept the system drive warning. Delete following folders:

- `C:\WINDOWS` - the old Windows installation directory
- `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users` - the shared user direcotry from the old instance
- `C:\Documents and Settings\{YourOldUsername}` - your user directory from the old instance

You will be asked if you really want to delete system files, read-only files etc. Always click *Yes to all*.

Comment: Well, I know I forgot to state that, but... One installs an operating system mostly because one has none... But anyway, very, very, good solution.

Now when I don't have a system installed, but I can manipulate the disk (MBR and such), is there a way to run the INSTALL\i386\winnt.exe from the drive? As the exe format is intended for Windows OS, which isn't present, how do I achieve that?

Comment: If you can't create bootable Windows disk, then use [HBCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/) (burn it to CD or [USB](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/usb-booting/)) to run WinNTSetup (it's built in). You won't have to use drive letter changing hack or to change Windows directory name, defaults will suffice. If you can't boot any external media, connect the HDD to another computer and use WinNTSetup there, but don't reboot. Connect the drive back and boot in the machine you want to install to.

Comment: Last two sentences exactly. Thank you. I'd upvote you, but I miss 2 rep.