# Formatting or not HDD after new motherboard installion

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, motherboard, ntfs

Is it possible to avoid formatting a hdd after installing a new motherboard on a machine? If "yes" is the answer, what is the best way to do that?

I need to install a new M/B on my machine, but I wish to keep the HDD without formatting. Is this possible? Or it will bring me headaches? If it is possible, what's the best way to do this? The OS is Win XP and the formatting is NTFS.

Comment: It depends. What OS are using? Are you wanting to reinstall the OS? Is the OS on this HDD? How is the HDD formatted (NTFS, FAT32, etc.) We need more information to be able to answer the question.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Installing a new motherboard doesn't mean you'd automatically format a hard drive. You may need to reinstall Windows, but that doesn't even require reformatting.

Comment: Let me put it more clearly. I need to install a new M/B on my machine, but i wish to keep the HDD without formatting. Therefore, i am asking: Is this possible? Or it will bring me headaches? If it is possible what's the best way to do this? The OS is win XP and the formatting is NTFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Installing a new motherboard won't automatically format the hard drive. Formatting is something you'd have to take explicit action to do.

Now, if the hard drive is the one hosting the OS and that OS is Windows, you may run in to problems. If it's the same brand and model of motherboard, Windows may require reactivation and/or a new license key, depending on your licensing. If it's a different brand or model of motherboard, you'll likely have to reinstall Windows to save yourself significant problems with the drivers. Even then, though, you don't generally have to reformat your drive.

As a good general rule, you'll want to make a full and reliable backup before making such a radical change. Additionally, as you probably know, Windows XP is well past its end of life and has known vulnerabilities making it unsafe to use in a networked environment.

Comment: Right! This is the answer i was looking for, thank you. Based on the solutions you propose, i guess it's a clean Windows installation that i must go for.

Comment: @gunnros You may be interested in [this](http://superuser.com/q/718048/194694) - you don't have to format to do a fresh install.